# how to access xml static resource in react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, metro-bundler

I want to add a static xml asset to my react native project and access it just like accessing images.

I added

```
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['png', 'xml'],
  },
```

to metro.config.js and `const asset = require('asset.xml')` returns me a number. But how to get the file content from this number?

Below code gets me a URI in development mode that I can use axios to fetch it, but in release mode it only returns a filename like `asset`, how to read it in release mode?

```
 Image.resolveAssetSource(asset).uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expo-asset](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/asset/) to get the `localUri`:

```
const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(require('path/to/your/asset.xml'))
```

Then you can use [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) to get the contents of the file as string:

```
const xmlString = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(localUri)
```

Then you can convert the xml string to a JS object with a package like [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser).

In order for this to work, you should edit your `metro.config.js` just as you mentioned above, namely: `assetExts` array should contain `xml`.

Also, if you use Typescript, you should add a declaration file, like `xml.d.ts` with the content of:

```
declare module '*.xml' {
  const moduleId: number; // the react-native import reference
  export default moduleId;
}
```

and that declaration file should be in a folder, that's added to `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig.json`.

Just a quick reminder: you can use this solution without Expo in a bare react-native app, you just have to install unimodules, which is described in the above links.

Good luck! :)